# @PersistenceUnit annotation not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, cdi

I want to use the @PersistenceUnit annotation in my app to create an application managed EntityManager

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="primary")


private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;        
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

This doesn't seem to be working.  I run my code through a debugger and discover that entityManagerFactory is null.  My guess is that the injection of Persistence context with the @PersistenceUnit annotation is not working.

My app is a CDI app.  It was not previously a CDI application - I converted it to CDI by creating a beans.xml file in WEB-INF, I needed to in order to do something like this.

Is there anything I need to configure within CDI to get the annotation to work?  Thanks.

Comment: are you using an application server, or is it tomcat?

Comment: I'm using JBoss 7.  This is a basic struts hibernate project deployed by Maven.  I'm only adding CDI in order to get this annotation working.

Comment: I'm not sure if @PersistenceUnit works on static fields.  I've never tried that.   Seems like that's not such a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have a JPA application running with only Java SE.  I don't have a WEB-INF/beans.xml, but I do have a META-INF/persistence.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="JPAPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>jpa.Container</class>
    <class>jpa.Item</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:D:\NetBeansProjects\JPA\jpaTestDB;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

`Container` and `Item` are the two persistence classes in my `jpa` package.

This was generated automatically by Netbeans.  There is also some information about using JPA without Java EE in the official (Sun/Oracle) Java EE tutorial in the persistence chapter.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why this person needs CDI to use JPA.   I use JPA in this way, inside EJB3 beans and inside ordinary POJO objects and it works.